# Refactor regex for address validation

Tags: angular, regex

I have the following regex for postal address validation in my angular app.

`const regx = '\\b([p]*(ost)*\\.*\\s*[o|0]*(ffice)*\\.*\\s*b[o|0]x)\\b'`

I only wanted this regex to pass for

**Match list:**

1. P.O.Box
2. pobox
3. post office box
4. 1234 post office box street
5. 123 postal office box

but it also matches for

**Do not match list:**

1. box
2. BOX
3. poor box

etc.,

How can I tighten this regex so it does not match the "Do not match list"? Also, I wanted my regex to be upgraded for things like postal office box or post office bin etc. Any inputs?

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples please try following regex. Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tgeujs/1) for used regex.

```
^(?:[0-9]*\s*[pP](?:\.O\.|o)(?:st(?:al)?\soffice\s)*[bB]ox(?:\sstreet)?)$
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```bash
^(?:                 ##Starting 1 non-capturing group from starting of the value.
  [0-9]*\s*          ##Matching 0 or more digits followed by 0 or more spaces.
  [pP]               ##Matching p OR P here.
  (?:\.O\.|o)        ##In a non-capturing group matching .O. OR o here.
  (?:st(?:al)?\soffice\s)*  ##In a non-capturing group matching st followed by spaces followed by office followed by spaces and keeping this non-capturing group Optional.
  [bB]ox             ##Matching b OR B followed by ox here.
  (?:\sstreet)?      ##In a non-capturing group matching space street and keep this optional.
)$                   ##Closing non-capturing group at the end of the value here.
```

Comment: I have just edited my question to clear some confusion. but the string can start or end with any char or numbers like 1234 po box street for example

Comment: @Brooklyn99, ok sure, regex has been updated successfully. For explanation will edit it in a min or so.

Comment: @Brooklyn99, Explanation of regex has been updated successfully now, cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another variant that should work for you:

```bash
/^(?:\d+\s*)?p\.?o\.?(?:st(?:al)?)?(?:\s+office)?\s*b(?:ox|in)\b.*/gmi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2rFHgS/2)

Since we we are using ignore case modifier here so we can use all lower case letters in our regex.